# How to show user information (name or avatar) on appBar?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to show logged user information (name, avatar, role) on `appBar`. I created some custom components : `layout`, `appBar` and `userMenu` How can I pass the logged user data to the `userMenu` or `appBar` component?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the **getIdentity** method of your **Auth** provider you want to return an object with this information in your Promise.resolve.  So it is somewhat indirect and not done within a custom AppBar itself.

Here is a snippet example from an auth provider:

```
getIdentity: () => {
    return Promise.resolve({ 
            id: userName, 
            fullName: userFullName,
            avatar: <Avatar />
        });
```

The Avatar aspect is optional of course and React-Admin will place its own avatar there if you leave that out.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be retrieving the user information from the authentication storage you are using on the client-side. 
In my case, I'm showing user initials instead of the standard avatar in the  component by pulling the information from the JWT token stored on localStorage.

```
decodeJwt(localStorage.getItem('token')).fullname
```

Probably not the best approach but worked for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/7042

This is what worked for me in my AuthProvider. I am using session-based authentication and don't have a jwt client side - so I expose an API on the server that provides the logged in user info. I don't have an avatar so I pass the user initials (only the first letter appears on the page)

```
getIdentity: async () => {
       const userinfo = await UserService.getUserInfo();
       const {id: id, userName: fullName, firstLastInitials: avatar} = userinfo;
       console.log(`getIdentity UserService user name is ${fullName}'`);
       return Promise.resolve({ id, fullName, avatar });
   }
```

and

```
const getUserInfo = async () => {
    const apiUri = HostApiServer();  // GET SERVER URI
    const mainResponse = await fetch(`${apiUri}/loggedInUser`, {
        method: 'GET'
        });
    const resp = await mainResponse.json();
    console.log(`UserService - GOT user info from ${apiUri}`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    return resp;
    };

const UserService = {

   doLogin,
   doLogout,
   isLoggedIn,
   getToken,
   getUserInfo
 };
```